# Android draw over navigation-bar

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Good morning Stackers!

I recently became a proud owner of a Galaxy S8. 
However, I was kind of dissapointed in Samsungs Edge Lighting feature.
So, I decided to throw myself into the world of android applications, and try to write a similar app myself.
Proud to say that I got pretty far, but, I'm not just here to share my successess.

My problem concerns the navigationbar. Since this is my first question on Stack, I'm not sure how to make this question organized, so I'll just put photo's here, with exeplenation underneath them.

I apologize for using links instead of posting images directly. I'm new to Stack and therefor don't have enough reputation points to post images. Sadlife.

This is a screenshot from my version of such a ring, without the navigationbar.

[My app *without* navigation-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFjeF.png)

Looks pretty good in my opinion! :3

However, if I take that to an application that forces the navigationbar to be shown, my "overlay" gets pushed up, like so:

[My app *with* navigation-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUl8w.png)

Let me now explain what I have tried so far.
Basically, I tried every combination of both View flags, as well as WindowManager.LayoutParams flags. I also messed around a lot with just the style of the overlay, in the XML file.

The screenshots you see above were taken with the following configuration:

For the LayoutParams:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_ATTACHED_IN_DECOR
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
```

For the View flags:

```
mTopView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    );
```

And the XML style for the overlay:

```
<style name="OverlayDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

The overlay Layout file itself looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/notification"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@android:id/navigationBarBackground"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/OverlayDialog" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/vector_drawable_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/vector_drawable"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:backgroundTintMode="src_in"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:theme="@style/OverlayDialog"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

I have also tried the WindowManager.LayoutParams with an offset on the y-axis, to force it down. This does work, but when you then, when you open an app that doesn't have the notification-bar, the overlay get's pushed back down, going below the screen (wish I could post a screenshot). 
Here is the code for that anyway:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(-1, -1, 0, -100, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_ATTACHED_IN_DECOR
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );
```

So, to wrap things up, I leave you with the question:
How do I create my layout such that it doesn't get pushed up by the navigationbar.

If you need any more information, please don't hesitate to ask!
Thanks in advance and take care!

Comment: I didn't  get much of your problem but i think you want that your bottom navigation bar should not interfere with the other parts of layout so i suggest you should go for per made bottom navigation activity given in Android studio  2.2 and above or you can use Coordinator layout which includes other layouts....

Answer (score 0):

I didn't  get much of your problem but i think you want that your bottom navigation bar should not interfere with the other parts of layout so i suggest you should go for per made bottom navigation activity given in Android studio  2.2 and above or you can use Coordinator layout which includes other layouts....

[image: Check out this layouts this gives some of the materiel design]

[image]

Source of images from http://www.androidauthority.com/using-coordinatorlayout-android-apps-703720/

[image]

Comment: Let me give a better example. Here is a screenshot of the music player, using Samsung's Edge Lighting. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzUwOxC6UUtRZ24wT0o5Mk1SVUU.  The Lighting goes beneath the navigation-bar, or I guess it "overlaps" the navigation-bar. My overlay gets pushed up by the navigation-bar, which is what i'm trying to prevent. Basically, I want my overlay to be fully edge-to-edge all the time, and not be interrupted my the navigation-bar. Hope this makes things more clear.

Comment: yes i get that you wanted a overlapping bottom navigation bar i would suggest if you are using android studio use bottom navigation when you are making a new project

Comment: also check the updated answer to see the image while making a new project select the selected bottom navigation activity.... this activity is per defined to handle suitations like yours

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks! However, my intuition (not that I'm an experienced programmer) says that the navigationbar created in that activity doesn't influence Android's navigationbar with the back, home, recents buttons. But I'll try it anyways!

Comment: I will also suggest if you want to keep the same activity then use Coordinate layout as the primary layout and include the other layout to it...